# call a module in same main file on rust

Tags: rust

it's possible to have a module declaration on the same main.rs file ?
i try to understand about modules declared on same file and submodules on a tree folder. it's not clear for me.  I've read about "pub(crate) mod func;" to use a submodule on a subfolder but i dont found a good doc to understand.

```
pub mod life {
    pub mod animalia {
        pub mod mammalia {
            println!("malamia");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
 
    life::animalia::mammalia();
}
```

i get this error:

```
 life::animalia::mammalia();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a function
```

i've read that "modules can be defined (not only declared) inline by adding a scope block:",  but never in main.rs ?

Comment: You can't call modules in Rust.

Comment: The code will work if you change `mod mammalia` to `fn mammalia()`. Functions can be called.

Comment: As the compiler also says: "note: the usage of `println!` is likely invalid in item context". This means your module isn't declared correctly anyway. You *need* a function here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mammalia` is not a function. To call it, it must be a function:

```rust
pub mod life {
    pub mod animalia {
        pub fn mammalia() {
            println!("malamia");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    life::animalia::mammalia();
}
```

```
malamia
```